# Error:java: Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later

Tags: java, maven

При запуске maven-проекта случилась следующая ошибка:

```
Error:java: Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Что бы вы не компилировали, но Java 5 оно не поддерживает. Установите в pom.xml целевую платформу помоложе:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: только что это сделал, но не помогло.

Comment: @VladLukiuanchuk отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте полностью pom.xml и полный текст вывода с ошибкой.

Comment: с 10 компиляции заработало, спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @VladLukiuanchuk если помогло, не поленитесь, отметье ответ галочкой.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler bytecode version -> target bytecode version 11

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]